# foreach,having wp_query inside, breaks after showing one result

Tags: categories, wp-query, php, tabs

I am trying to make category tabs that show posts from selected category tab. I have tried it my way but m getting only one post for each category, whereas it should return all post in that category. I am pasting the code below, can anyone help me sort this issue ?

```
<ul id="download-tab" class="nav nav-tabs resp-tabs-list">
                        <?php
    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'parent' => 13
      );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
$i=0;
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $i++;
    echo '<li><a id="#'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $category->name)).'" href="dtab'.$i.'">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
}
?>
 </ul> 

           <div class="tab-content resp-tabs-container" id="download-content">

<?php
$pargs = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 13
  );
$categories_loop = get_categories( $pargs );
foreach ( $categories_loop as $category_loop ) {
query_posts('category_name='.$category_loop->slug.'&posts_per_page=-1&order=desc'); $j=0;
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
  $j++ ?>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="dtab<?php echo $j ?>">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th>DATE</th>
                            <th>TITLE</th>
                            <th>SIZE</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    <?php 
    $file_size = rwmb_meta('file_size');
    $file_url = rwmb_meta( 'file_url');
  ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $file_size; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo $file_url ?>" class="button3 download_btn" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>

    <?php 
    endwhile;  ?>
<div style="width:45%; float:left;  font-weight:bold; margin-top:20px;"><?php //previous_posts_link('PREV'); ?></div>
<div style="width:45%; float:right; text-align:right; font-weight:bold; margin-top:20px;"><?php //next_posts_link('NEXT',$download_query->max_num_pages); ?></div>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no content found.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; 
} ?>
```

Comment: You are sure that you have more than 1 post in each category? Also, `query_posts()` is frowned upon. Use [`new WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)  instead. And I would also suggest that once you have it all figured out, you use the [Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to improve performance on all those queries.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, yes there are more posts in every category. And i had also tried using new WP_Query but got the same result

Comment: Ok, just wanted to check the basics first.

Comment: so what can be done ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are only getting 1 post returned. Your query args look correct, even if as I mentioned in the comment you should be using `WP_Query`. Therefore, if I had to guess, I would say your looped html markup is off? And is maybe not printing the results correctly.  I've modified your code to only have 1 `get_categories()` and categories loop. I don't know if it is more or less "readable" this way, but it seems to work for me.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 13
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );

$tabs = '';
$panes = '';

if( $categories ){

    $tabs .= '<ul id="download-tab" class="nav nav-tabs resp-tabs-list">';

    $panes .= '<div class="tab-content resp-tabs-container" id="download-content">';

    $i=0;

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $i++;
        $tabs .= '<li><a id="#'.$category->slug.'" href="dtab'.$i.'">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';

        $post_args = array( 'category_name' => $category->slug, 
                            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                            'order' => 'desc' ); 

        $category_posts = new WP_Query( $post_args );

        $panes .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="dtab' .$i . '">';

        if ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) :

            $panes .= '<table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th>DATE</th>
                            <th>TITLE</th>
                            <th>SIZE</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>';

            while ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post(); 

                $file_size = function_exists( 'rwmb_meta' ) ? rwmb_meta('file_size') : '';
                $file_url = function_exists( 'rwmb_meta' ) ? rwmb_meta( 'file_url') : '';

                $panes .= '<tr>
                            <td>'. get_the_time('d/m/Y') .'</td>
                            <td>'. get_the_title() .'</td>
                            <td>'. $file_size .'</td>
                            <td><a href="'. $file_url .'" class="button3 download_btn" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a></td>
                        </tr>';
            endwhile;

            $panes .= '</table>';

        else:
            $panes .= '<p>' . __( 'Sorry, no content found.' ) . '</p>';
        endif;

        $panes .= '</div><!--#dtab' .$i . '-->';

    }

    $panes .= '</div><!--#download-content-->';

    $tabs .= '</ul><!--#download-tab-->';

}

// print it all out
echo $tabs;
echo $panes;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm. Can you please tell me where was i making mistake ?

Comment: Like I said, I am not 100% sure. It could be improperly closed mark up, though that looks ok to me. It could also be that `wp_reset_query()` is in the wrong place.

Comment: May be wp_reset_query() is the culprit. I also want pagination/pager in the tab-pane, if you see my code i have put one. Can you help me place it, it would be wonderful.

Comment: If you have `"posts_per_page"=>-1` then you should be getting *all* the posts and thus have no need for pagination. Additionally, you are showing content in a tabbed format... where would you be linking to?

Comment: ya i know it is a bit illogical, is there any way out if i have lot of content in the tab-pane

Comment: You'll need to remove the `posts_per_page` parameter. You could do some kind of "load more" via Ajax? I don't really know and we're getting sort of off-topic.